# Android: Gradle - Module Dependency Issue - Unable to find symbol

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, dependencies, android-library

There are two modules in the Android project

1. app
2. database

database build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.sample.lib:lib-v7:27.1.1'

}
```

app build.gradle:

```
dependencies {

        implementation project(':database')
    }
```

Now in the app I am able to get references to the files in sample lib. 
But when the apk is to be built i get the following error:

```
error: cannot find symbol class SampleLibClassA
```

Why am I getting this error even when **database** module is added to **app** module as a dependency?

It works if I add the **SampleLib** dependency separately again the app module. But doesn't that defeat the whole purpose and wouldn't that just mean duplicate dependencies. Why is there a need to add them separately?
Am I missing something here?

Thanks.

Comment: anyone........?

Answer (score 0):

> Now in the app I am able to get references to the files in sample lib.

This is not exactly true. You need to use `api` instead of `implementation` in the database build.gradle to make it working as you expect.

```
dependencies {
    api 'com.sample.lib:lib-v7:27.1.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can actually happen if you are using `minifyEnabled true` in the module `build.gradle` file in the `buildType`.

In case you have this, just set it to `false` and build again.